# Where can I sell a plug-in for Final Cut Pro or Premiere Pro?

Tags: plugins

I've created a great plug-in. Where can I sell it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about video production - it is about selling a product. While the visitors here may be familiar with many products in the video production space, this does not make the question on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe have a [marketplace](https://www.adobeexchange.com/creativecloud.html) for plugins and scripts for all the apps across the CC range, and there's also [AEnhancers](http://aenhancers.com/) for After Effects and Premiere plugins and scripts.

Answer (score -1):

So far I've been able to find three major paths for selling a plug-in, at least on the Mac.

First, you can always set up your own store through something like SquareSpace or Wix. That works if, somehow, you have enough web traffic or can quickly get enough visitors through Twitter, Facebook or whatever to at least view your site and continue on to buying your plugin. This takes a lot of marketing and web site development effort, but beyond credit card processing fees and such, you get to keep all the revenue.

Second, you can publish it as part of an app on the Mac App Store. I haven't seen this done too often, but it seems to work. I don't know what it would take to get Apple to feature a plug-in sold this way, but it would be great if you can pull it off. Apple takes 30% of the sales, but it's a known entity.

Third, you can go through a store like FxFactory or CoreMelt's VFX Market. I've used plug-ins from them for a while, but never tried to sell a plug-in through them. That's where this question came from, actually. These guys all seem to also take 30% of the sales, but they're likely to reach a lot of potential customers.

The biggest problem I see with Apple, FxFactory and VFX Market is that they're Mac exclusive. You can publish plug-ins for Final Cut Pro X, Premiere Pro on Mac, After Effects on Mac and Motion. With your own store, you can publish for Windows too.

Given that I don't even know how to write a plug-in for Windows yet, those solutions work for me, but it would be awfully nice to know how to sell a Premiere Pro/After Effects plug-in for Windows, or if there are any other markets out there for plug-in developers to sell into.